# Ubuntu terminal transparency is not working as expected

Tags: 13.04, transparency

Upon changing the settings of my terminal's transparency using the sliding bar, it simply turns darker, i.e. the transparency is reduced further.

my graphics card: Intel Ivy Bridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

So please do suggest something guys... Thanks.!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the transparency of gnome-terminal using [gconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gconf-editor/).

1. Open gconf-editor.
2. Go to *app > gnome-terminal > profiles > Default*.
3. Set the value of *background-darkness*.

[image: gconf]